# C# check whether value is present in the List<> or not

Tags: c#

What is the efficient way to check whether the value is present in the `List` or not and then insert the value, in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method to check whether value is in the list:

```
if(!valuesList.Contains(value)) 
{
  valuesList.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: How does contains check for equality? with .Equals ( == )? You might run into a problem with using reference types

Comment: For reference types you can implement [IEquatable<T>.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx). Check [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) docs, it's explained there.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) and [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx):

```
if (!myList.Contains(myValue)) {
    myList.Add(myValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) and [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1), quick example:

```
if (!theList.Contains(theValue))
{
    theList.Add(theValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use method `bool List.Contains(T)` for check, and `void List.Add(T)` for addition

or create extension:

```
public static void AddIfNotExist<T>(this List<T> list, T item)
{
    if (list.Contain(item))
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

using `list.AddIfNotExist(item)`